# mysql trigger ckeck constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

i have an error , when i want to create a trigger to check new entry in salle table 
i have a salle table (nSalle,nbComputer,responsible) 
i want to ckeck before insertion  if nSalle is in ( 1,2,3,4,5) otherwise, i will restrict the insertion

i have created a trigger ,i have no error but when i insert a value != ( 1,2,3,4,5) i get it inserted witch is not what i want

her is my code so far

```
delimiter // 

create trigger before_insert_salle before insert
on salle
for each row
begin
(nSalle,nbComputer,responsible) 
if new.nSalle in (1,2,3,4,5) then 
 set new.nSalle = new.nSalle,
     new.nbComputer = new.nbComupter,
     new.responsible = new.responsible ; 
end if ; 
end //
```

when i insert a record like so

`insert into salle values (10,20,'Joe')` is works , witch is wrong 10 is not in (1,2,3,4,5 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to signal an error when the constrain is violated.  MySQL now lets you do this with `signal`:

```
delimiter // 

create trigger before_insert_salle before insert
on salle
for each row
begin
declare msg varchar(255);
if new.nSalle not in (1,2,3,4,5) then 
    SET msg = concat('Constraint on nSalle violated: invalid value ', cast(new.nSalle as varchar(255)));
    SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = msg;
end if ; 
end //
```

The documentation on `signal` is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html).

Comment: i get an error  ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'msg'

Comment: I added the declare statement.